# List to changes and return the ids of the objects that had changes in React

Tags: reactjs

So I have two states in React, one is a copy that doesn't change, and the other one changes, so with a use effect I'm listening for changes to the array that changes and call a function, which the main function is iterate the arrays and check two specific values if they did change in case they are not same while compared to the old state, return the id of that object and put into an array, and at the end return it.

So:

```
const [oldData, setOldData] = useState(...old data here)
const [newData, setNewData] = useState(...new data here)

useEffect(() => {const ids = Compare(oldData, newData)} => [newData])

const Compare = (oldData, newData) => {
  for (let keys in oldData) {
    if (newData[keys] && oldData[keys] !== newData[keys]) {
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you can make use of filter method and get the id's